# Published content is not visible to anonymous user

Tags: workbench

I have installed the [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) module (version 7.x-1.2) on my 7.38 Drupal install.

Everything is working fine as far as an original author changing the status of a page from "Draft" to "Needs Review" and the page then showing up in an approved users workbench to review.

The problem is that if the reviewer finds an issue and then changes the status from "Needs Review" back to "Draft" with some notes and sends it back to the original author, the page DOES NOT show up in the original authors workbench. It actually completely disappears from the original author and doesn't show anywhere. The reviewer can see it in THEIR Drafts tab, but that's it.

This obviously isn't right. Has anyone else seen this or have a fix for it?

Second one is when the reviewer moderate state from needs review to published then content is not shown to anonymous user.